# Add a text comment in a numeric cell with Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, cells

Is there a way with Excel, to put a comment with a numeric cell, like the cell A3 here:

[image]

**such that formulas like `=SUM(A1:A5)` still work?**

Here the wanted result would be 19.

Here it doesn't work because A3 is parsed as a text cell. Sometimes it would be useful to put a number in a cell, with a comment to explain this number.

Is there a trick to do this without creating an extra "comment" column?

Comment: You can add the "comment" with a **Custom Format**.  It will be visible, but not interfere with the maths.  There is a limit to the number of these formats you can use, however.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent How do you enable this feature (maybe can you post an answer with this)?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent How would you define a custom format `<numbers>;<text comment>`? I tried this: https://imgur.com/gv8gFmL but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily done using the comment feature. Once you enter your number in a cell and press `enter`, select that cell and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and you will see an option to add comment right there. See this:

[image]

It works quite well and the shortcuts ensures that you don't have to switch between tabs or use your mouse much. 
The commented cells are marked by a small coloured triangle at the top as shown above. Also, editing the comment is pretty easy. Select and use the shortcut once again.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: I don't see how this is any different from my answer, aside from the Shift+F2 shortcut.

Comment: Both answers are useful @RoobyDooby, the shortcut is helpful too!

Comment: @RoobyDooby, shortcut makes the task easier and one doesn't have to switch between tabs :)

Comment: I don't disagree, but perhaps you could have just added a comment to my answer rather than creating a whole new one. Oh well.

Comment: @Sanu_012 What's the equivalent of SHIFT+F2 for LibreOffice Calc? (If you can include this in your answer, it could be great for future reference)

Comment: @Basj I have never used LibreOffice till now since MS office suffice my needs. But yeah, once I start using it, I will :|

Comment: @RoobyDooby, when you posted your answer, I was busy typing my answer as well. So, you know, I didn't notice until I posted this :)

Comment: @Sanu_012 Understood. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me your problem could be solved simply using the Comment tool already in Excel (Review > New Comment):

[image]

This has the benefit of being "hidden" (aside from the indicator in the top right corner of the cell) until you mouse over the cell.

Comment: Nice idea! I just tried, but the UI/UX is not perfect: you have to hover the mouse cursor over the cell during ~ 1 sec to see the comment. Also if you want to modify it, you have to go to *Review > Modify comment*. Trying to double click on the comment does not work (the tooltip goes away).

Comment: That is all true. You do have the option to "Show/Hide Comment" which would make it visible permanently, but the size of the comment box obscures a number of other nearby cells.

Comment: We always appreciate people who donate their time and effort to Suggested Edits.  However, if you are going to propose an edit like [this one](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/978573), please be a bit more careful to ensure that you don't simply change one misspelled word for another one.  That simply creates that much more work for the reviewers.

Comment: @Run5k I apologize for missing the misspelling of the one word in the edit I suggested. This seems like an odd place to point it out though.

Comment: Perhaps it is @RoobyDooby, but we don't really have another viable way to contact Super User community members.

Comment: @Run5k I hadn't considered that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Select your cell and apply this *Custom Format*:

**General" (reason: blah)"**

[image]

**NOTE:**

- the pseudo-comment resides in the same cell as the number
- the pseudo-comment is always visible and does not rely on "mouse-over"
- the pseudo-comment does not interfere with formulas involving the cell

Comment: Thank you! But do we have to go to "Format Cell", and modify the "Type" field for each cell with a different comment?

Answer (score 1):

If you can do two things:

1. Enforce the folks entering data always usign a space before they type anything for the reason, and
2. Be sure that you remember, always, into the future, to do any summing, etc., using the following technique,

then you can simply type the numbers, and reasons, if any, as in your example.

The (a) way to "condition" the entries for use in `SUM()`, for instance, is like so:

```
=SUM( IFERROR( VALUE( LEFT( A1:A5, FIND( " ",A1:A5 )-1 ) ), A1:A5 ) )
```

The idea here being to use `FIND()` to locate the space, using that less 1 to find the length of the number entry in the cell, and taking the `LEFT()` that many characters, then converting to a value with... `VALUE()`.

When there is a bare number, that won't work as an error is generated, hence the `IFERROR()` wrapping it and giving the bare number itself if an error in the test/"het a number" calculation occurs.

And that gives `SUM()` values it can work with.

(VERY often Excel can use a textual numeral as an actual number, but often/usually not when a string function is involved. Otherwise, it could be simply the `LEFT()` portion of the formula.)

Must have the space, or some other enforced beginning to mark the start of the chaff to remove. Must then always remember you can't rely on the cells directly. In three years, that might not be at the front of your mind. Of course, in practice, you would quickly see failure, probably, if forgotten, so the need is really to document NOW the way to overcome it so you don't have to luck out and just happen to be looking at a formula summing something to jog your memory.